# Unable to populate select dropdown in dynamically generated form in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to populate a select dropdown after the form gets generated through a JSON. Unfortunately, the data is not getting reflected in the dropdown.

HTML -

```
<div *ngFor="let element of formTemplate?.controls">
    <div [ngSwitch]="element.type">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
             <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="text" placeholder="{{element.label}}" formControlName="{{element.field_name}}" />     
             </mat-form-field>
        </div>


        <div *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
             <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>{{element.label}}</mat-label>
                       <mat-select formControlName="{{element.field_name}}">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of element.options" [value]="option">
                               {{option}}
                          </mat-option>
                       </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

TS -

```
this.formTemplate = {
    "controls": [{
      "type": "text",
      "label": "First Name",
      "required": true,
      "field_name": "first_name"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "label": "Country",
      "required": false,
      "field_name": "country",
      "options": this.countryNameArr
    }]
};

let group = {};    
this.formTemplate['controls'].forEach(input_template=>{
  group[input_template.field_name]=new FormControl('');  
});
this.popupForm = new FormGroup(group);

//POPULATING DATA HERE
this.countryNameArr = ['India', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Australia'];
```

The data in countryNameArr is not reflecting in the UI. There are few conditions also where I need to populate the data after creating the formgroup. How can I achieve this?

This is the stackblitz demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmkwac

Comment: `this.formTemplate = { controls: [`

Comment: Jep, what you have after `this.formTemplate  = ` isn't a valid object literal. You need to either turn it into an array or state keys. It's a syntax error and should be marked as such in your editor.

Comment: @VladGincher Ya It is there. I forgot to add here in the example.

Comment: @ChrisG Ya It is there. I forgot to add here in the example. That's not an issue

Comment: So update the question with the correct code

Comment: Right. The first thing I'd try is to populate `this.countryNameArr` *before* creating the `FormGroup`.

Comment: @ChrisG True that but There are few conditions also where I need to populate it after creating the formgroup.

Comment: So does that fix it? In that case you need to recreate the formgroup each time the options change.

Comment: That would fix it. But that's not the requirement. I don't think that recreating the formgroup is a good idea. Other elements might also suffer in that. Right?

Comment: I guess, in that case you need to use one of the available [methods](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#methods) to update the FormGroup.

Comment: @sajalsuraj Are you sure that order or use and initialization is same as you posted in the question?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes. You can suggest your way also.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmkwac @PrashantPimpale